# Cómo descargar un archivo pdf y doc desde php?

Tags: php, archivo

Estoy intentando descargar un archivo por medio de php pero me está resultando muy complicado. Sabéis cómo poder hacerlo? He encontrado esto pero no me funciona, carga caracteres especiales cuando lo único que quiero es que se descargue o visualice.

Pongo el código que estoy utilizando pero no sirve.

```
 <?
    if ($_POST[Descargar]) { 
        $file ="cv0.pdf"; 
        $filename = "cv0descargado.pdf"; // el nombre con el que se descargará, puede ser diferente al original 
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"\n"); readfile($file); 
        }
    ?>
```

Gracias.

Comment: ¿No te da errores con $_POST[Descargar]? , probaste $_POST['Descargar'] y usar el isset y empty

Answer (score 3):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Descargar'])) { 
  $file = 'cv0.pdf';
  if (is_file($file)) {
    $filename = "cv0descargado.pdf"; // el nombre con el que se descargará, puede ser diferente al original
    /*header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");*/
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    readfile($file);
  } else {
    die("Error: no se encontró el archivo '$file'");
  }
}
?>
```

Por un lado compruebo que esté definido el campo POST "Descargar" (entre comillas, en caso contrario saltará otro mensaje de advertencia que indica que la constante ha sido cambiada a cadena) y posteriormente compruebo que realmente exista el archivo que quieres enviar al usuario y por último he eliminado el espacio en blanco que había antes de la apertura de la etiqueta de PHP (`<?`).

Si no quitas ese espacio te saldrán advertencias diciendo que las cabeceras ya han sido enviadas y otros mensajes de advertencia similares.

Prueba y me cuentas.

Comment: He optado por la solución: $enlace = $registro['Curriculum'];
            echo "<a href=\"$enlace\" target=\"_blank\">Ver Currículum Vitae</a><br><br>"; // Aquí abro el pdf ya que de la otra manera me muestra el pdf con caracteres especiales: tipo -> --- rocSet [/PDF /Text] /Shading 9 0 R /Font 10 0 R >> endobj 10 0 obj << /F0 11 0 R /F1 12 0 R >> endobj 9 0 obj << /FHShade0 13 0 R >> endobj 8 0 obj << /Length 1124 /Filter [/FlateDecode] >> stream x��VMs ---- Muchas gracias por el aporte.

Comment: Deberías averiguar la raíz del problema. El usuario final gana descargando directamente del servidor web sin pasar por el módulo de PHP (resumir descarga en caso de cortarse, conocer el tamaño de la descarga si no creas la cabecera, etc), pero he conocido casos que el alojamiento gratuito de PHP/MySQL trataba de inyectar HTML de publicidad y eso rompía la descarga. Puede ser que el servidor que usas o su firewall L7 esté borrando alguna cabecera que estás creando, etc. Siempre puedes hacer uso de la consola de depuración de Chrome/Firefox para ver qué cabeceras te genera realmente el servidor.

Answer (score -1):

Agrégale este código:

```
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');
```

En la [página de la W3C (en inglés)](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html) se indica que (traducción propia):

> El campo Content-Transfer-Encoding se usa para indicar el tipo de transformación que se ha usado para representar el cuerpo (body) en una manera aceptable para ser transportado.

En este caso indicarías que es un tipo binario.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe qué hace tal código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.